# SailsJs - cannot generate api (using v0.10.0-rc8)

Tags: frameworks, sails.js

I cannot make generation work using beta SailsJs (v0.10.0-rc8).
I tried this and that but with no success.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

`~/dev$ npm -g ls | grep sails
├─┬ sails@0.10.0-rc8
│ ├── grunt-sails-linker@0.9.5
│ ├── sails-build-dictionary@0.10.1
│ ├─┬ sails-disk@0.10.1
│ ├─┬ sails-generate@0.10.3
│ │ ├── sails-generate-adapter@0.10.4
│ │ ├── sails-generate-backend@0.10.13
│ │ ├─┬ sails-generate-controller@0.10.6
│ │ ├── sails-generate-frontend@0.10.18
│ │ ├── sails-generate-generator@0.10.11
│ │ ├── sails-generate-gruntfile@0.10.10
│ │ ├─┬ sails-generate-model@0.10.9
│ │ ├── sails-generate-new@0.10.16
│ │ ├── sails-generate-views@0.10.1
│ │ └── sails-generate-views-jade@0.10.0
│ ├── sails-stringfile@0.3.2
│ ├─┬ sails-util@0.10.2`

`~/dev$ sails new project
info: Created a new Sails app 'project'!`

`~/dev/project$ sails generate api user
error: No generator called 'controller' found; perhaps you meant 'sails generate api controller'?
error: No generator called 'model' found; perhaps you meant 'sails generate api model'?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this with a fresh install of Sails.  Maybe there's a problem with your Sails install?  Try:

```
npm cache clear
sudo npm uninstall -g sails
sudo npm install -g sails@beta
```

Comment: Thanks. I did reinstall multiple times but it didn't work back then. Strange thing. Doing it now went okay. Btw, it's `npm cache clean`.

Comment: Btw, apart from the `clear`/`clean` typo - we don't need the `sudo` so I edited your answer, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: `npm cache clear` is an alias for `npm cache clean`; they both do the same thing.  And it may not be true in your specific case, but in general (on *nix systems) you need to `sudo` to globally install a package, since it copies files into protected folders.

Comment: My bad about the `sudo`, I forgot I am using `nvm` so globally installed packages go into a subdir of my home dir. Btw `npm cache --help` shows `clean` only and I usually stick to what's documented officially. Anyway, thanks :)